RecyclerView date and month for a week on Kotlin
I would like to implement that RecyclerView that shows date and month for a week included  current date. and that needs to be scrollable and current date should be center. I understand that I need Adapter and ViewHolder for RecyclerView but I have no idea how to implement date and month. Please help me.
I need to implement these

Past 2 weeks from current date
Current date
Future 1 week from current date

listitem_date.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <data></data>

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="30dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/text_date"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:fontFamily="@font/ttnorms_medium"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="60sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            tools:text="12/31" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</layout>

Adapter.kt
class Adapter(private val data: ArrayList<Date>) : RecyclerView.Adapter<ViewHolder>() {

    private lateinit var binding: ListitemDateBinding

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
        binding =
            DataBindingUtil.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context),
                R.layout.listitem_date,
                parent,
                false
            )
        return ViewHolder(binding)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int =
        data.size

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        
    }

}

ViewHolder.kt
class ViewHolder (
    private val binding: ListitemDateBinding
) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(binding.root){

    fun bind(date: Date){
        val currentDateTime = LocalDateTime.now()
        val format = SimpleDateFormat("M/d", Locale.US)
        val cal = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US)

        val currentDate = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US)
        val currentDay = currentDate[Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH]
        val currentMonth = currentDate[Calendar.MONTH]


        binding.textDate.text = currentDateTime.toString()
    }

}


I don’t think you are using SimpleDateFormat and Calendar for anything? That’s good. Those classes had design problems and are long outdated. Your LocalDateTime (or other class from java.time) can give you all the date and time functionality that you need. If for example you need the date in M/d format: currentDateTime.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("M/d", Locale.US)). If you only need the date, prefer LocalDate. It also has fine methods for calculating the dates and weeks before and after today. Do get rid of the old-fashioned classes.
